# CMakeLists issue with shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer, clion, pkg-config

I trying to use gstreamer-rtsp-server by this way:

1. I downloaded [gst-rtsp-server source](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-rtsp-server/) and compiled and installed it using `./configure`, `make`, `make install` as usual.
2. After this I create simple CLion project with the code from the gstreamer-rtsp-server sample(`gst-rtsp-server-1.6.0/examples/test-launch.c`)
3. CMakeLists looks like this:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
   project(gst_RTSP_server)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
   include(FindPkgConfig)
   pkg_check_modules(GLIB glib-2.0 REQUIRED) 
   pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER
       REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0) 
   pkg_check_modules(GSTRTSP
       gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0)
   include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   include_directories(${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   include_directories(${GSTRTSP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp) 
   add_executable(gst_RTSP_server ${SOURCE_FILES}) 
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLIB_LIBRARIES}) 
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES}) 
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} gstvideo-1.0)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GSTRTSP_LIBRARIES})
   ```

After all this I successfully built my project but when I run it I get output:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgstrtspserver-1.0.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it and run my project?

Comment: What is content of variable `GSTRTSP_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev `GSTRTSP_LIBRARIES=gstrtspserver-1.0;gstbase-1.0;gstreamer-1.0;gobject-2.0;glib-2.0`

Comment: So these libraries are not in your search path(RPATH). Thing that these libraries are found during link stage is unrelated to searching them when executable is running. See [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) for more info about handling RPATH in CMake projects.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks again, your answer is right - when I set working directory as "/usr/local/lib" I can run my app, but if I use `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)` in CMakeLists (as written in [this article](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling#Common_questions)) then I get nothing, why?

Comment: This option affects on *installed* file (created by `install(TARGET)` command), not on built one (created by `add_executable()`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, you should write an answer.

Comment: @dragn: Currently I am unsure that hardcoded value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` (or setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH`) is *the best way* for decide the problem. It looks strange for me that even *built* binary cannot be loaded. So I am not ready for post an answer. You are free to post your answer, if you want.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, for my project I've set up to copy shared libraries to the binary output folder as a post_build step. This makes it more portable, as I can distribute binary output dir to another system without worrying about whether that system has needed libraries. The problem is it involves a lot of CMake coding, including my own FindPackage modules.

Comment: I wish CMake had an option to bundle shared libraries along with executable :)